# How can I use a 1-argument function in an "ANY"/"ALL" query?

Tags: postgresql

Assuming I have the following function:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfun(IN TEXT)
     RETURNS boolean
     LANGUAGE SQL
     IMMUTABLE
     LEAKPROOF
     AS $CODE$
         SELECT COALESCE(
             $1 ILIKE ANY (ARRAY[
                 'test',
                 'bar'
             ]),
             false
         );
     $CODE$;
```

Which returns `true` if `$1` matches `'test'` or `'bar'`.

How can I use this function in another `ANY` query? For example:

```
 SELECT myfun ANY(ARRAY['hello', 'world']);  -- should return false
 SELECT myfun ANY(ARRAY['hello', 'foo']);  -- should return true ('foo' matches)
 SELECT myfun ANY(ARRAY['test', 'world']);  -- should return true ('test matches')
```

But this syntax is incorrect. And I don't quite know how to properly write this.

---

**edit:** more detail

In essence what I want to do is check if any one of a set of columns contains any one of forbidden terms. In other words, I have a set of forbidden terms, and have to check multiple columns for containment of that word. This will later be used in a RLS policy. In the example below, the function `contains_forbidden_term` is the function I would like to be able to write.

A small but important note: The same functions must be applied to other tables, but with varying number of arguments (hence the array as argument-type).

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    name TEXT,
    last_name TEXT
);
CREATE USER bob;
ALTER TABLE foo ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

CREATE POLICY bob_foo ON foo TO bob USING (contains_forbidden_term(ARRAY[name, last_name]));

GRANT SELECT ON foo TO bob;
```

Comment: You can use the original function with: `SELECT (true = ANY (select myfun(x) from unnest(ARRAY['test', 'world']) as x )) ;`

Comment: Or this: `SELECT bool_and(myfun(x)) from unnest(ARRAY['test', 'world']) as x ;`

Comment: Or `SELECT true = ANY (select myfun(unnest(ARRAY['tt', 'foo']))) ;`

Comment: Consuming a set of values and returning a scalar result is essentially aggregation. Is it possible to create a custom aggregate function in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @AndriyM Yes it is (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/xaggr.html). But I think the solution submitted by ypercube is maybe better to convey the "meaning" of the code. While the result is the same, semantically I am not aggregating anything. Rather I checck if *any*thing matches. So future readers of the code might better understand the intent of that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the first function with `ANY` but you have to have a valid syntax as you found out (`<expression> <**operator**> ANY ...`). So the following would work (the "trick" piece is to use `unnest()` whild unfolds the array into rows):

```
SELECT true = ANY (select myfun(x) from unnest(ARRAY['test', 'world']) as x) ;
```

or the more compact:

```
SELECT true = ANY (select myfun(unnest(ARRAY['tt', 'foo']))) ;
```

Comment: This is *way* cleaner than what I came up with, and works like a charm. `unnest` was pretty much the puzzle-piece I was missing. Thanks a bunch ;)

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, it seems that the syntax for `ANY/ALL` queries must be

```
<expression> <**operator**> ANY ...
```

I continued my work in that direction and came up with the following which works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myoperator(IN boolean, IN TEXT)
RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
LEAKPROOF
AS $CODE$
    SELECT COALESCE(
        $2 ILIKE ANY (ARRAY[
            'test',
            'bar'
        ]),
        false
    ) = $1;
$CODE$;

CREATE OPERATOR <<< (
    PROCEDURE = myoperator,
    LEFTARG = boolean,
    RIGHTARG = TEXT
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION contains_forbidden_term(IN TEXT[])
RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE plpgsql
LEAKPROOF
IMMUTABLE
AS $CODE$
    BEGIN
    RETURN NOT (true <<< ANY($1));
    END
$CODE$;

SELECT true <<< ANY (ARRAY['foo', 'bar']);
SELECT true <<< ANY (ARRAY['this', 'is', 'ok']);
```

But this seems a bit like a roundabout way to do something simple and I wonder if I did not get caught up in a rabbit-hole while wearing 
blinders not seeing an easier solution (nb: I also updated the question with more detail).